# Cant figure out how to go through array in Swift and find specific data

Tags: arrays, swift

Hello I have question about `arrays`.

I have an `array` with following data, also I have corresponding Struct for `SpiritRelation()`:

```
var spiritRelations = [
        SpiritRelation(relationName: "Thunder Lantern", relationSpirit1: "Razor", relationSpirit2: "Lamp Genie", relationSpirit3: "", relationSpirit4: "", relationStats: "Double resist +5%, ATK +1600", relationSpiritIcons: ["razor", "genie"]),
        SpiritRelation(relationName: "Illusive Fantasy", relationSpirit1: "Heavenly Maiden", relationSpirit2: "Lamp Genie", relationSpirit3: "", relationSpirit4: "", relationStats: "Excellent strike +15%, Dmg Penetration +15%, Max HP +11500", relationSpiritIcons: ["maiden", "genie"]),
        SpiritRelation(relationName: "Grand Demonlord Gathering", relationSpirit1: "Sand Golem", relationSpirit2: "Lamp Genie", relationSpirit3: "", relationSpirit4: "", relationStats: "Excellency Resist +20%, Double Dmg +5%, ATK +1600", relationSpiritIcons: ["golem", "genie"])
    }
```

`array` which contains data which will be selected by user:

```
var selectedSpiritsForRelation = [String]()
```

*array of type String because I put there values which corresponds to image names in Assets. I need that to display images*

`array` where I want to keep found relations and use it to display all found `relationStats` in UI

```
var foundRelations = [SpiritRelation]()
```

**My problems is:**

lets say user has selected 2 spirits for example: `selectedSpiritsForRelation["golem", "genie"]`

I’m able to find and save correctly found relation by

```
let result3 = spiritRelations.filter{$0.relationSpiritIcons == (selectedSpiritsForRelation) } // = 3rd relation in spiritRelations[]
foundRelations.append(contentsOf: result3)
```

but after user select another one spirit and array become: `selectedSpiritsForRelation["golem", "genie", "maiden"]`
same code as for `result3` does not work anymore, because how I understand it tries to filter exactly combination of 3, but my expectation is that 2nd relation from `spiritRelation[]` will be found also

and here is my problem, I cant figure out how to correctly go through `spiritRelations[]` and find all relations related to `selectedSpiritsForRelation[]` every time user selects new spirit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `allSatisfy` in your filter by checking that all `relationSpiritIcons` elements exists in `selectedSpiritsForRelation`

```
foundRelations = spiritRelations.filter { 
    $0.relationSpiritIcons.allSatisfy { icon in
        selectedSpiritsForRelation.contains(icon)
    }
}
```

Comment: I was very close to `allSatisfy`, but could not imagine that I can use right in the filter.

Comment: idk if u will see this message, but if yes, maybe you could give me some advice on other topic. My `spiritRelations` will have more than 40-50 relations and currently they all are located in one ViewController - would it better if I move them out of this ViewController in a separate file? or it is fine to have such a huge array?

Comment: I would lift them out